# Faster way to check a long case statement with || conditions

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have switch case statement with 5 cases.
One of this 5 cases looks like:

```
switch (Number)
   {
   case 1:
      CallSomeFunction1();
      break;
   case 3:
      CallSomeFunction3();
      break;
   case 4:
      CallSomeFunction4();
      break;
   case (2 || 7 || 8 || 9 || 12 || 14 || 18 || 19 || 22 || 23 || 25):
      CallSomeFunction();
      break;
   case 6:
      CallSomeFunction6();
      break;
  }
```

The switch case is executed on a realtime system every 10ms. 
What will be the (or is there any) fastest way to check against those case statement?

Comment: Is that *really* how the case looks?

Comment: Ok, I corrected it for a better view.

Comment: Oh, you didn't correct what I was asking about

Comment: That code will not compile in standard C, see my answer.

Comment: ahh, yea, you are right! This can not compile in standard c.

Comment: For the sake of readability, I would use an array of function pointers, `CallSomeFunction[Number]();`. Just ensure that `Number` is in range first. Compilers will however struggle to inline code with function pointers. In order to reason in detail about what will be fastest, we would need to know the system used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you present should not compile: `(2 || 7 || 8 || 9 || 12 || 14 || 18 || 19 || 22 || 23 || 25)` is `1` in C, and that's a duplicate case label.

A compiler will optimise the corrected

```
case 2: case 7: case 8: ... case 25:
    CallSomeFunction();
    break;
```

with remarkable proficiency (possibly with a *jump table*). Check the generated assembly code if you're in any doubt. It will probably be faster than using an array of function pointers set up so you could write `SomeFunctions[Number]();`.

Either of these approaches will probably be faster than writing a function that transforms 2, 7, 8, ..., 25 to a constant expression.

In your case though you could write

```
default:
    CallSomeFunction();
```